# Dynamic binding in C++ @

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, Pls help me with this ,how the compiler is doing dynamic binding even when the class1,class2 and class3 are not using inheritance like base class and derived class relationship -> class derived :: public class base{};

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Class1{
    public:
    virtual void f(){
        cout << "f() in class 1\n";
    }
    void g(){
        cout << "g() in class 1\n";
    }

  };

class Class2{
    public:
    virtual void f(){
        cout << "f() in class 2\n";
   }
   void g(){
        cout << "g() in class 2\n";
   }

};

 class Class3{
 public:
    virtual void f(){
        cout << "f() in class 3\n";
    }

   };

 int main()
  {
       Class1 object1, *p;
       Class2 object2;
       Class3 object3;
       p = &object1;
       p->f();
       p->g();
       p = (Class1 *)&object2;
       p->f();
       p->g();
       p = (Class1 *) &object3;
       p->g();
    return 0;
   }
Output:
f() in class 1
g() in class 1
f() in class 2
g() in class 1
g() in class 1
```

Answer (score 4):

**Undefined behaviour.**

Casting between completely unrelated types and accessing their contents is undefined behaviour, so anything could happen, including appearing like things worked.

Don't do this.

Additionally, using a C-style cast in that context is analogous to a `reinterpret_cast`. You should avoid using this as much as possible. If you use `static_cast`, for example, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Got your point,by using reinterpret_cast we are forcing the compiler to cast the unrelated types and if we try to use static_cast it will give compile time error as the types are not related.Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the explanation of what is happening here:
1.) if at least one virtual function is present in a class then a vtable is created for the class and a vptr for the calling object by the constructor. This vtable contains only the virtual functions. Every polymorphic call then is resolved by the compiler during run-time (dynamic binding) from the type of object the pointer refers to rather than the type of the pointer itself.
So, here:
2.) class 1 would have a vtable , let's call vtable(class 1). Then vtable(class 2) and vtable(class 3). There would be 4 vptrs, vptr(object 1), vptr(p), vptr(object 2) and vptr(object 3).
3.) So, when the calls; p = (class 1*)&object 2; p->f(); and p->g() are resolved at runtime, the compiler would look for the object vptr of object referred by p, i.e object 2; though it is casted but still the referred object is object 2 hence vptr(object 2) would be invoked which would search for virtual function f in vtable (class 2) and call it. While searching for g() it vptr won't find it in vtable and hence go for the type of pointer itself which is class 1 and call class 1's g.
4.) Note that: virtual function has got to do with polymorphism and not inheritance.